# python writing to a file

Tags: python

I keep getting this "writing to a closed file error" while trying to compile the following code:

```
fout = open('markov_output.txt', 'w')  

for i in range( MAXGEN ) :
            # get our hands on the list
    key = (w1,w2)
    sufList = table[key]
            # choose a suffix from the list
    suf = random.choice( sufList )

    if suf == NONWORD :     # caught our "end story" marker.  Get out
            if len( line ) > 0 :
                    fout.write(line)
            break
    if len( line ) + len( suf ) > MAX_LINE_LEN :
            fout.write(line)
            line = ""
    line = line + " " + suf

    w1, w2 = w2, suf
    fout.close()
```

Comment: Why are you closing the file **inside** the loop?  That would probably only write one record and then the file would be closed.  Is that what you intended?  Or is your indentation wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you want the `fout.close()` outside the loop??

You might want to consider using [`with`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/with.html) if you have Python 2.5 or newer:

```
with open('markov_output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    # Your code to write to the file here
```

That will automatically close the file when you're done, as well as if any exceptions occur.

Comment: Note that in Python 2.5 you have to use `from __future__ import with_statement`.

Answer (score 5):

You're closing `fout` each time through the loop.  Un-indent `fout.close()` and it should work as expected.

Comment: And because he is Glyph, another +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

`fout.close()` seems to be inside the for loop.

Un-indent that line, for the intended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your `fout.close()` occurs inside the `for` loop. It will be closed after the first item, not at the end of the operation.

For clarity/robustness, it is recommended to use the `with` operator when dealing with files.